# Sorting vectors, that contains class objects, in C++ by class member's in order

Tags: c++, vector

What I aim is that I would like to sort the vector by following criteria;
I sorted the whole vector by "name" and when "name"s are equal, I want it to sort by "surname" etc. Here is the following code:

Below I created a class;

```
class NotLearning {
public:
    NotLearning(); // Constructor
    int getID()const; // Function to used to initialise private variable "ID" of the class via the constructor.
    int getDay()const; // Function to used to initialise private variable "day" of the class via the constructor.
    int getYear()const; // Function to used to initialise private variable "year" of the class via the constructor.

    double getAverage()const; // Function to used to initialise private variable "average" of the class via the constructor.

    std::string getName()const; // Function to used to initialise private variable "name" of the class via the constructor.
    std::string getSurname()const; // Function to used to initialise private variable "surname" of the class via the constructor.
    std::string getCity()const; // Function to used to initialise private variable "city" of the class via the constructor.
    std::string getMonth()const; // Function to used to initialise private variable "month" of the class via the constructor.

private:
    int ID;
    int day;
    int year;

    double average;

    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    std::string city;
    std::string month;
};
```

I sort the vector, that consists of class objects, by the class member of "ID" with the following code:

```
void sortVectorByID(std::vector<NotLearning>& newClass)
{
    std::sort(newClass.begin(), newClass.end(), cmp_by_id);
}
```

In which "*cmp_by_id*" define like that;

```
bool cmp_by_id(const NotLearning& one, const NotLearning& two) // compare classes inside the vector by checking the member of "ID".
{
    return one.getID() < two.getID();
}
```

So far I have sorted the vector successfully. After that, I implemented the following code for my purpose;

```
void sortVectorByDetail(std::vector<NotLearning>& newClass)
{
    std::sort(newClass.begin(), newClass.end(), cmp_by_detail);
}
```

Where "*cmp_by_detail*" defined like that;

```
bool cmp_by_detail(const NotLearning& one, const NotLearning& two) // compare classes inside the vector by checking the members in order.
{
    bool compare_result = cmp_by_id(one, two);
    if (compare_result)
        return compare_result;

    compare_result = cmp_by_average(one, two);
    if (compare_result)
        return compare_result;

    compare_result = cmp_by_name(one, two);
    if (compare_result)
        return compare_result;

    compare_result = cmp_by_surname(one, two);
    if (compare_result)
        return compare_result;

    compare_result = cmp_by_city(one, two);
    if (compare_result)
        return compare_result;

    compare_result = cmp_by_day(one, two);
    if (compare_result)
        return compare_result;

    compare_result = cmp_by_month(one, two);
    if (compare_result)
        return compare_result;

    compare_result = cmp_by_year(one, two);
    if (compare_result)
        return compare_result;

    return true;
}
```

I did not give all codes in the class, just in order not to distract you. However, I leave [GitHub](https://github.com/Ahmopasa/StructUsage)
here if you wanted to see all codes.

I hope I could tell you what I need.

I thank you deeply for sparing your time if you came to this line ^^.

Have a nice day.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I get an error that says *debug assertion failed invalid comparator* when I called *sortVectorByDetail()* function. 
I also below leave the way I used to call these functions;

```
#include "LearningCpp.h"


int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    std::vector<NotLearning> myClass;
    fillVector(myClass);
    showVector(myClass);

    sortVectorByDetail(myClass);
    showVector(myClass);  
}
```

**Edit: I now solved my problem with following implementation to the function of *cmp_by_detail*. Code is here;**

```
bool cmp_by_detail(const NotLearning& one, const NotLearning& two) {

    if (one.getID() != two.getID())
    {
        return one.getID() < two.getID();
    }

    if (one.getAverage() != two.getAverage())
    {
        return one.getAverage() < two.getAverage();
    }

    if (one.getName() != two.getName())
    {
        return one.getName() < two.getName();
    }

    if (one.getSurname() != two.getSurname())
    {
        return one.getSurname() < two.getSurname();
    }

    if (one.getCity() != two.getCity())
    {
        return one.getCity() < two.getCity();
    }

    if (one.getDay() != two.getDay())
    {
        return one.getDay() < two.getDay();
    }

    if (one.getMonth() != two.getMonth())
    {
        return one.getMonth() < two.getMonth();
    }

    if (one.getYear() != two.getYear())
    {
        return one.getYear() < two.getYear();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your comparison does not give a strict weak ordering. (You're lucky that your library implementation checks this.) Read [the requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for the ordering function.

Comment: I have solved my problem right now. Thanks for the help ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Implement one function pointer for sort function.

```
bool cmp(NotLearing a, NotLearning b)
{
    if(a.getName()==b.getName())
       return a.getSurname()<b.getSurname();
    return a.getName<b.getName();
}
```

then sort your vector

```
vector<NotLearning> v;
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),cmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check all function which you are using in `cmp_by_detail`. Somewhere in function assertion must be failing. [Take a look at this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549289/invalid-operator-assertion-in-sort)

Comment: When I sort by single calls of functions inside **cmp_by_detail** function via _sortVectorByID_, _sortVectorByAverage_ etc. I don't get any error and successfully sort respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare certain 'properties' of two instances of the same class lexicographically you can make use of [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple).  With that your `cmp_by_detail` implementation becomes...

```
bool cmp_by_detail (const NotLearning &one, const NotLearning &two)
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(one.getID(), one.getAverage(), one.getName(),
                                 one.getSurname(), one.getCity(), one.getDay(),
                                 one.getMonth(), one.getYear())
         < std::forward_as_tuple(two.getID(), two.getAverage(), two.getName(),
                                 two.getSurname(), two.getCity(), two.getDay(),
                                 two.getMonth(), two.getYear());
}
```